# Recognizing noisy images with background patterns

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a hobby project where I need a fast way of filtering out images that are filled with either noise or a repeating pattern like these:

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pkf8.jpg)

so I can get down to the business of recognizing features like these:

[Pieces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R57Vg.jpg)

The feature recognition works reasonably well when there *is* a feature, but I need to filter out the blank squares first (feature matching is also pretty slow).

Currently I am doing ad hoc things eg.

- (for the hatched examples) count jumps in value as we go from top left to bottom right and along a line in the center
- apply gaussian blur, convolve two quadrants, and take some normalized maximum. If it's high enough, we probably have a blank.

But this involves a cutoff that I have to tune by hand, which is not at all robust. Eg. the hatched patterns can have scanning artifacts that will break the first one.

Is there some canonical method that I can use as a fast first pass here? Hopefully using python PIL etc.

Comment: what's the purpose of this?

Comment: Image recognition: program converts an image of a chessboard (scanned and noisy) into a text string describing the position - which can be fed into standard chess software. It analyses each of the 64 squares in turn. After a lot of work, I have it working pretty well on the pieces (knight, bishop etc) but get errors on blank squares. The examples show some typical patterns that are used in chess books.

Comment: I am not sure why you have problems here. Getting the blank fields should be the simplest part. what features are you talking about?

Comment: Blank means representing a blank square on the chessboard. So in the actual image it looks like one of the [examples](https://imgur.com/gallery/jYV2Z) I linked to in my question. As you can see, it's some simple repeating pattern.

Comment: yes I understood that, but what is your problem here? you have 64 fields. >= 32 are empty and they should be very different from each other and from occupied fields.

Comment: How do you propose I measure the difference in a way that is robust against noise? And without assumptions about the pattern on the blank squares (which can also show up in the background of the occupied squares)?

Comment: average intensity, standard deviation, dominant spacial frequencies, gradients, pca,... various texture analysis metrics... I don't think you can get a robust method without extensive teaching so why not simply teach every figure for different print styles right away.